# Why can't the infix increment operator (++) be used for an IIFE?

Tags: javascript, function, iife

I'm learning javascript and I'm struck at `IIFE` syntax.

I have understood that to write `IIFE` we need to make the function as expression and then invoke it.

We can make it as expression by wrapping function in between `()`. Or prefixing the function keyword with `+`,`-`,`~`,`!`.

Now for the problem, when I prefix with `++` I'm getting error in the console.

**Code:**

```
++function(){console.log("hello")}();
```

**Error:**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side expression in prefix operation
```

Why can't I use `++`? `++` is a unary operator and I thought it will make the interpreter to think anonymous function as function expression just like `+`,`-` etc., did.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `++foo` is the same as `foo = foo + 1`. Since `function() {} = function(){} + 1` isn't a valid operation, it will throw an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### It can't be assigned to

As the error message says, the function()... is not a valid left-hand side expression, i.e., it cannot be assigned *to*.

+, -, ~, ! will cause the expression to be *evaluated*. On the other hand, the increment operator (++) will cause the expression not only to be evaluated, but also *modified*, which isn't allowed for this expression.

Answer (score 3):

`++` *modifies* the value of the right hand side *in place* therefore you must put something on the RHS that can store whatever the new value is. The return value of a function call is passed to the left but isn't a place of storage itself.